# GCC Optimization results in "Undefined symbol" at runtime

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc

I right now have a problem that is rather confusing to me:
I have piece of software written in C++ and that links against a library in C. I include the header classes using the usual

```
extern "C" {
    #include <libheader.h>
}
```

Everything works fine as long as I do not use gcc's optimization. Once I turn on even -O1, thus the first optimization level, during runtime I get an "undefined symbol" error for an symbol from this library. However, the name has gone through name mangling which should be disabled cause of the `extern "C"`.

The function that calls the symbol in question is inlined, in case this matters. The used compiler is gcc 4.4.3.

I honestly don't even have an idea what to search for, so I would be really grateful if one of you could give me some reason for this behaviour.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Can you remove the inline (i.e. make the function not inline) and see if it starts working?

Comment: Alternatively to @satuon's suggestion, could you make the inline function call a C++ function that wraps the C function, and see if that makes it start working?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried both suggestions, however, the symbol is still not found.

Comment: At runtime??? How on Earth can one get an "undefined symbol" error at *runtime* in a *compiled* language? Are you using dynamic libraries of some sort?

Comment: @AndreyT I think that is quite the usual behavior for shared libraries that include another shared library. Had this problem more than once yet (with different causes, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the header that defines the calling inline function includes the library's header *without* the `extern "C"` wrapper, and everywhere else the wrapper lines are used?

Did you try other levels like `-O2`?

Did you try uninlining your function?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Yes, the header of the correct file certainly uses the `extern "C"` wrapper. -O2 and -O3 have the same effect. As stated above, removing the inline does not help either.

Comment: @Thilo Specifically, you removed the inline AND moved the function from the header to a source file so the compiler couldn't decide to automatically inline it?

Comment: Argh... Thank you for clarifying. Forgot to move the previously inlined function to a source file. This solves the problem. However, the result is not really elegant, as having the function inlined could be significantly faster.

Answer (score 4):

You say that you're including the `libheader.h` file in an `extern "C"` block, but that the symbol the linker is looking for has been name-mangled.

That's an indication that `libheader.h` is also being included outside of the `extern "C"` block (the include inside the `extern "C"` block is probably a nop due to include guards in `libheader.h`).

Look for other ways that `libheader.h` might be getting included.  GCC's `-E` and/or the various `-M` options may or may not help with this.  Or (if only for a test) move the `extern "C"` block inside `libheader.h`:

```
// at start of libheader.h:
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* existing contents of libheader.h */
// ...

// at end of libheader.h:
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Note that linkage specifications can nest, so you don't have to remove the existing `extern "C"` blocks at the `#include` sites.

I don't know why the problem would happen only for optimized builds, except that maybe the .c or .cpp file that contains the non-inline version of the calling function gets the headers right, and there only needs to be one translation unit that gets the headers wrong and inlines the calling function to see the problem.

Comment: Thank you! That might be a good idea how to track down the problem, if that's the reason. Sadly, I will only have time to look into it next week friday, will report back then.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function that is defined when not inlined but not defined when inlined, then the problem should be pretty simple to define.

You have used the function somewhere without including its header file.

Review all the files that call this function and make sure the header is included.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a C header with `extern "C" {...}` doesn't always work;
generally, headers need to be designed to work with both languages for
them to work with both languages.

In this case, without more details, it's hard to say exactly what is
happening, *but* the `inline` keyword means different things in C and in
C++; I would not expect a header with `inline` functions to work in this
way.  (Off hand, I wouldn't expect the symptoms you're getting, but they
don't especially surprise me either.)

The correct way of handling this is to insist that the supplier of the
library provide a header which is designed to work in both languages.

Failing that, the correct way to handle this is to write your own
C code, which includes the header and wraps all of the functions you
need, and to write your own header for this C code, which is designed to
be included from both languages.  Which is, I'll admit, a lot of work;
get the supplier to do his job, rather than having to do half of it for
him.